# Timezone and Clock wrong for Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, timezone

When launching the emulator either from Run As -> Run Configurations -> Targets

Selecting the emulator (in my case GalaxyS4_4.2.2) : made from recommendations on Samsung's developer site.

I am passing Additional Emulator Command Line Options : -timezone "America/New_York"

but when my emulator starts the time zone is still wrong.

I have also tried from command line: emulator -avd GalaxyS4_4.2.2 -timezone "America/New_York"

but i still get the wrong time when the emulator boots.

I followed this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this to not be an issue with other version of API for Android. Not sure why but this looks like a bug with the 4.2.2 API running on an emulator.

I made a change to my emulator and targeted kitkat instead of jellybean and all my:

```
 `-timezone America/New_York`
 `-timezone America/Los_Angeles`
```

etc are working with this API.

so unfortunately if anyone is using that version of JellyBean on your emulator you will run into this issue and have to manually change it each time you run the emulator in:

Settings App -> Date & time -> uncheck default 'automatic date & time' and 'automatic time zone' and set it manually.